# PHP Mailer compile and store message for later sending

Tags: php, phpmailer

Can we compile and store messages as a draft in PHP mailer and then later on send each message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It *is* possible to do this with PHPMailer. After configuring the PHPMailer instance with everything you'd normally need to send the message, do not call `send()` - instead call `preSend()` (which constructs the message) and then get the message content using `getSentMIMEMessage()`, e.g.

```
$mail->preSend();
$message = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
```

`$message` will then contain a complete RFC822 message which you can stick in a database, queue or whatever to send later. To do the actual sending later, you could make use of [PHPMailer's SMTP class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php) directly. To see how to drive that class, look at [PHPMailer's `smtpSend()`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L1188) function.

Comment: You'll also have to store recipient and sender mails or get it back from saved RFC822 message (To: and From: lines) to use PHPMailer's SMTP class directly

Comment: I made this work, but slightly different than was suggested here. Contact me if you want details. The benefit to me is that it is easier to store the MIME message in the database than a variaty of fields, inline images, attachments, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so PHPMailer supports this feature. But you can do this by using DB Table. Create a table in database to store messages, recipients, from, headers, etc and send them by PHPMailer later from a CRON job.

Answer (score 1):

The `PHPMailer` library at this moment has the `getSentMIMEMessage` function which saves the message in a compact way, but the library doesn't have a counterpart yet to send saved email message.

So the best way to do at the moment what you need it's to **serialize** the PHPMailer object, save the string on a database or in a file and restore it after when you want to send it.

Here are the functions I created to queue mails which cannot be send in a script.

`$file` should contain full path and filename.

```
function sendQueuedMailFile($file) {
    $rfcMail = file_get_contents($file);

    $phpMailerObj = new PHPMailer();
    $phpMailerObj = unserialize( $rfcMail );

    if ( $phpMailerVar->postSend() ) {
        // If sent correctly, delete file
        unlink( $file );
    }
}
```

This function saves a phpMailer object to a queue file. The phpMailer object **must** have all the addresses, subject, content with the values needed to do a normal mail sending before calling this function.

```
function queuePHPMailerToFile($phpMailerObj, $file) {
    $phpMailerObj->PreSend();
    $phpMailerObj->GetSentMIMEMessage();
    
    $rfcMail = serialize($phpMailerObj);

    file_put_contents($file, $rfcMail);
}
```

You can use the `queuePHPMailerToFile` function for queue mails for later sending or to save a mail which cannot be sent at this moment, and try to send it the next time you try to send one email.

When you call the `send()` method of the PHPMailer object you can check the result. If it went ok send previously queued emails, if the sent failed queue current message for next time. `$queuePath` should contain the folder where you would like to save queued mails.

```
if ( $phpMailerObj->Send() ) {
    // Mail sent ok, trying to look for queued emails
    sendEmailQueue($queuePath);
} else {
    // Some problem detected, saving mail for next time
    queuePHPMailerToFile($phpMailerObj, $queuePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . date("Y-m-d_Hisu") . "_" . rand(0, 999999) . ".txt");
}
```

And for ending this it's the function to re-send queued files

```
function sendEmailQueue($queuePath) {

    if ( is_dir($queuePath) ) {
        if ( $dh = opendir($queuePath) ) {
            
            while ( ($file = readdir($dh)) !== false ) {
                
                if ( ($file == '.') or ( $file == '..' ) ) continue;
                
                sendQueuedMailFile($queuePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work, can someone assist please, has anyone managed it or came across any gotchas:


     $eml = file_get_contents($filename);
     $mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
     $mailer = unserialize($eml);  --> ERROR: unserialize(): Err at offset 0
      ...
     $result = $mailer->postSend();

Comment: The contents of the $filename file was serialized before saving it?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this question when trying to do this myself - I wanted to store the PHPMailer object in a database to send it later from a different server, to have a mail queue to limit number of emails sent per second and also to push back messages when there was a sending error.

The solution is easy - instead of

```
$phpmailerObject->send();
```

just do a:

```
$phpmailerObject->preSend();
```

Then serialize the object in a database. When you want to later save the mail, get the database entry, unserialize the object, and do a:

```
$phpmailerObject->postSend();
```

Internally, PHPMailer just does a preSend() and postSend() if you send() an object instance. Using preSend() before saving the object is important because you mime headers and body will be created, with all attachments and data. If you do the preSend() on a different server with a different setup, the attachment files/images may not be found and there will be an error. postSend() only sends the data with the "compiled" email.

I would also advise to create every PHPMailer instance with "true" in the constructor (to enable exceptions) and to wrap the postSend() in a try/catch-block to handle any sending/SMTP errors. I learned that the hard way.

Answer (score -1):

PHPMailer can't support this, because it conserves the Email message in Object which will die after the end of the script(the HTTP protocol works that way).

If you want to send them latter (say after 15 minutes) you need to use CRON job indeed and make a script looking in the database and sending emails.

If you want to send them in the Lifetime of the script (send them after the  tag) you can simply do an array of emails and `foreach` them at the end

Answer (score -1):

You need create

1. special method that will do save all mail that should be sent (in db)
2. special method that will get all unsent mails and send them
3. add to crontab method that send unset mails

That's all.