# Mailgun + phpMailer + GoDaddy

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, mailgun

Please excuse newbie language because i am exactly that.

I am hosting myDomain.com on GoDaddy (registered in Asia)
I have deployed a phpScript for which i originally had a frustrating time validating credentials but finally succeeded thanks to the help of the forums here. (NB my SMTP Host was smtpout.asia.secureserver.net and SMTP Port =80 - none of the other ports would work)

I have now setup a subdomain on GoDaddy mailgun.myDomain.com and have verified this on Mailgun. creating a simple info@mailgun.myDomain.com i also succeeded in applying the necessary MailGun SMTP credentials to a Gmail account such that i can be managed from there - sending and receiving not a problem.

However, i am now unable to apply those same SMTP credentials via PHPMailer. THis has been discussed many times i know - and i've read through as best i can but have had little success finding a solution. I came across a recent reply from Synchro

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291223/7802270

"Build your message as you would normally in PHPMailer, then call preSend() and getSentMIMEMessage() instead of send()."

Can i assume this is with reference to the class.phpmailer.php file?
And if so - i'm not sure i'm reading his comment correctly but do i then replace all instances of send() with getSentMIMEMessage()? or preSend()? It can't be both...

Thank you in advance for any clarifications

Comment: preSend() checks all your settings and builds the message, getSentMIMEMessage fetches a complete message. You do those two instead of calling send(), because you're not sending, you're just getting a message as a string to send some other way.

Comment: Thanks Synchro, i found the code example you posted 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212634/php-mailer-compile-and-store-message-for-later-sending

but not being a competent programmer i will need to find assistance to to help me apply to my script.

I will post separately the section of script in question to see if i the stackoverflow community can recommend where to apply the changes needed!